# How to refer to a table by name in SQLite C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have

```
 [Table("Foods")]
    public class Food
{
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Weight { get; set; }
  
}
```

Just in case:

---

```
CREATE TABLE Foods
```

equivalent

```
database.CreateTable<Foods>()
```

---

```
INSERT INTO Foods
```

equivalent

```
database.Insert(food)
```

---

Question:
I want to create every day

```
database.CreateTable<Foods>()
```

and daily create table but with different name.

If I create it like this
`CREATE TABLE Foods27/01/2022`, I will change the name every day. No problem! And if I want to make changes, I'll just call by name `INSERT INTO Foods27/01/2022`

But how to do it using the `database.Insert(food)` option?

Comment: Would it not be easier to add the date as a column to your table (and as a property to your object) ?

Comment: Don't do it. You're storing in the table name data that should be stored in a column of the table. (It's the same as creating a new class Foods27_01_2022 every day in your program and recompiling it and releasing new - you wouldn't do it; don't make new tables either)

Comment: To Luuk: I want to have a list of tables for each day. It seems to me more logical than having one table, with a selection by the date of addition. But of course, if I can't find anything else, I'll follow your advice.

Comment: To Caius Jard: yes, I understand that when creating a new table, I create a new class every time. But the question was more philosophical, why is it possible to access via sql query, but not via C#.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use fluentApi to do such behavior.

The ToTable method is applied to an entity to specify the name of the database table that the entity should map to.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
        .ToTable("Food"+suffix);
```

And add a constructor on you context that receive the suffix as a parameter.